# AngularJS ui-router: how to resolve typical data globally for all routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service

I have an AngularJS service which communicates with the server and returns 
translations of different sections of the application:

```
angular
     .module('utils')
     .service('Translations', ['$q','$http',function($q, $http) {
        translationsService = {
            get: function(section) {
                if (!promise) {
                    var q = $q.defer();
                    promise = $http
                            .get(
                                '/api/translations',
                                {
                                    section: section
                                })
                            .success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
                                q.resolve(result.data);
                            })
                            .error(function(data,status,headers,config){ 
                                q.reject(status);
                            });
                    return q.promise;
                }
            }
        };

        return translationsService;
    }]);
```

The name of the section is passed as the `section` parameter of the `get` function.

I'm using AngularJS ui-router module and following design pattern described [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-skinny-angularjs-controllers)

So I have the following states config:

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('users', {
        url: '/users',
        resolve: {
            translations: ['Translations',
                function(Translations) {
                    return Translations.get('users');
                }
            ]            
        },
        templateUrl: '/app/users/list.html',
        controller: 'usersController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .state('shifts', {
        url: '/shifts',
        resolve: {
            translations: ['Translations',
                function(Translations) {
                    return Translations.get('shifts');
                }
            ]            
        },
        templateUrl: '/app/shifts/list.html',
        controller: 'shiftsController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
```

This works fine but as you may notice I have to explicitly specify `translations` in the resolve parameter. I think that's not good enough as this duplicates the logic.

Is there any way to resolve translations globally and avoid the code duplicates. I mean some kind of middleware.

I was thinking about listening for the `$stateChangeStart`, then get translations specific to the new state and bind them to controllers, but I have not found the way to do it.

Any advice will be appreciated greatly.

Important note:
In my case the resolved `translations object` must contain the translations data, not service/factory/whatever.

Kind regards.

Comment: I don't have time to write up an answer, but I should mention that state definitions are simple javascript objects.  You can put them in a list (put the `name:` declaration as a nested attribute of each state) and loop over each one.  On each state you iterate over, add the resolve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though this is a very old question, I'd like to post solution which I'm using now. Hope it will help somebody in the future.
After using some different approaches I came up with a [beautiful angularjs pattern by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#routing)

He suggest using a special service `routerHelperProvider` and configure states as a regular JS object. I'm not going to copy-paste the entire provider here. See the link above for details. But I'm going to show how I solved my problem by the means of that service.

Here is the part of code of that provider which takes the JS object and transforms it to the states configuration:

```
function configureStates(states, otherwisePath) {
    states.forEach(function(state) {
        $stateProvider.state(state.state, state.config);
});
```

I transformed it as follows:

```
function configureStates(states, otherwisePath) {

    states.forEach(function(state) {

        var resolveAlways = {

            translations: ['Translations', function(Translations) {

                if (state.translationCategory) {

                    return Translations.get(state.translationCategory);

                } else {

                    return {};

                }

            }],

        };  



        state.config.resolve =

            angular.extend(state.config.resolve || {}, resolveAlways || {});



        $stateProvider.state(state.state, state.config);

    }); 

});
```

And my route configuration object now looks as follows:

```
        {
            state: ‘users’,
            translationsCategory: ‘users’,
            config: {
                controller: ‘usersController’
                controllerAs: ‘vm’,
                url: ‘/users’.
                templateUrl: ‘users.html'
            }
```

So what I did:

I implemented the `resolveAlways` object which takes the custom `translationsCategory` property, injects the `Translations` service and resolves the necessary data. Now no need to do it everytime.

Answer (score 25):

Let me show you my approach. There [is a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KwjZmyX9Z6SWNClNNMqe?p=preview)

Let's have a `translation.json` like this:

```
{
  "home" : "trans for home",
  "parent" : "trans for parent",
  "parent.child" : "trans for child"
}
```

Now, let's introduce the **super parent state** `root`

```
$stateProvider
  .state('root', {
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
    resolve: ['Translations'
      , function(Translations){return Translations.loadAll();}]
  });
```

This super root state is not having any `url` *(not effecting any child url)*. Now, we will silently inject that into every state:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
      parent: 'root',
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
  .state('parent', {
      parent: 'root',
      url: "/parent",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
```

As we can see, we use setting `parent` - and do not effect/extend the original state *name*.

The root state is loading the translations at one shot via new method **`loadAll()`**:

```
.service('Translations', ['$http'
    ,function($http) {
    translationsService = {
      data : {},
      loadAll : function(){
        return $http
          .get("translations.json")  
          .then(function(response){
            this.data = response.data;    
            return this.data;
          })
      },
      get: function(section) {
        return data[section];
      }
    };

    return translationsService;
}])
```

We do not need `$q` at all. Our super root state just resolves that once... via `$http` and `loadAll()` method. All these are now loaded, and we can even place that service into `$rootScope`:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Translations',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, Translations) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    $rootScope.Translations = Translations;
}])
```

And we can access it anyhwere like this:

```
<h5>Translation</h5>
<pre>{{Translations.get($state.current.name) | json}}</pre>
```

*Wow... that is solution profiting almost from each feature coming with UI-Router... I'd say. All loaded once. All inherited because of $rootScope and view inheritance... all available in any child state...*

Check that all [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KwjZmyX9Z6SWNClNNMqe?p=preview).

Comment: Thank your for the reply. Unfortunately, this won't work in my case as I'm working on the very large scale application and there are thousands of translations. Loading them at once is impossible. Also, I need to have an object which contains translations which I can access by key. Not the service which I call from templates: like {{ translations.home }}.

Comment: My solution is a concept. You do not have to load all that. I just show you how to do it differently. Just call $http in the get.. but check my solution...