# AngularJS, How to get resolve value using a factory with $http?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have declared a state using ui-router and am trying to perform a resolve. However, I cannot return a value in my resolve using a $http in a factory. Below is one way that I've tried.

It appears that the `success` callback runs too late so that nothing is actually returned inside the resolve. When the `success` callback does run, it produces the desired result.

```
...
.state('book', {
    url: '/book',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        '': { 
            templateUrl: 'templates/book.html',
            controller: bookController
        }
    }
})
.state('book.detail', {
    url: '/{chapter}/{pageName}',
    resolve: {
        pageIdNumber: ['$http','$stateParams', 'myFactory', function($http, $stateParams, myFactory) {
            return myFactory.getPageIdNumberUsingPageName(
                function(response, $stateParams) {return response[0];}, // console.log(response[0]) gives the desired result but nothing is returned. I think this function runs too late.
                function(response) {return response[0];},
                $stateParams.pageName);
            }]
    },
    views: {
        'page@book': { 
             templateUrl: 'templates/page.html',
             controller: pageController
         }
    }
})
...

myFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
function myFactory($http){
    return {
        getPageIdNumberUsingPageName: function (callbackSuccess, callbackError, pageName){
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://example.com/api/get_page_id.json',
                cache: true,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                data: 'page_name=' + encodeURIComponent(pageName),
            })
            .success(function (response) {
                callbackSuccess(response);
            })
            .error(function (response) {
                callbackError(response);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You need to use `promise` based setup for resolve to work. Callbacks do not work. See this video https://thinkster.io/egghead/resolve

Comment: Check an example here http://stackoverflow.com/q/28237952/1679310...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `resolve`, you must return a `promise` object - you cannot return a value:

```
...
.state('book.detail', {
    url: '/{chapter}/{pageName}',
    resolve: {
        pageIdNumber: ['$http','$stateParams', 'myFactory', function($http, $stateParams, myFactory) {
            return $something; // $something must be a promise object and not a value like "2" or "dog".
            }]
    },
...
```

However, the code provided in the question uses a factory to retrieve a value. We must change the factory so that it retrieves a `promise`. To do this, we note that the `success` method returns values and the `then` method returns a promise:

```
    function myFactory($http){
        return {
            getPageIdNumberUsingPageName: function (callbackSuccess, callbackError, pageName){
                $http({
                    ...
                })
                .success(function (response) {
                    // response contains values like "2" and/or "dog"
                });
            }
        };
    }

    function myFactory($http){
        return {
            getPageIdNumberUsingPageName: function (callbackSuccess, callbackError, pageName){
                $http({
                    ...
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    // response contains a promise object that, when eventually fulfilled, will produce values like "2" and/or "dog"
                });
            }
        };

}
```

So, the factory changes to:

```
myFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
function myFactory($http){
    return {
        getPageIdNumberUsingPageName: function (pageName){
            return $http({     // notice the "return" here
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://example.com/api/get_page_id.json',
                cache: true,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                data: 'page_name=' + encodeURIComponent(pageName),
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data[0]; // data[0] contains the value that I want. response is a promise object
            });
        }
    };
}
```

And the `resolve` becomes (read the comments in the code):

```
...
.state('book.detail', {
    url: '/{chapter}/{pageName}',
    resolve: {
        pageIdNumber: ['$http','$stateParams', 'myFactory', function($http, $stateParams, myFactory) {
            return myFactory.getPageIdNumberUsingPageName($stateParams.pageName); // this returns the $http object in the factory; that factory in turn returns the promise object.
            }]
    },
    views: {
        'page@book': { 
             templateUrl: 'templates/page.html',
             controller: pageController
         }
    }
...
```

Comment: this seems too complicated